# SQL Server Connection String with Port doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string

The scenario: SQL Server 2014 Developer with default settings and connection port (1433), C# with Entity Framework 6.

Using SQL Server with EF6 in my C# app, the following connection string works like a charm:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog =...
```

But this connection string fails:

```
Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog =...
```

Yes, this is the correct port.

Snooping around in the configurations of SQL Server I found a solution by activating the TCP/IP protocol, but, since it's the default port, isn't it supposed to work just like the other connection string without the port? Even with the TCP/IP deactivated (which is the default)?

Thanks!

Comment: @lad2025 You *do* specify it with a `,`, not a `:`.

Comment: It might be the case that it's communicating using `named pipes` in the first instance, but in the second instance since you're specify a port it's forcing it to use `tcp/ip`.

Comment: A client can't connect even to localhost if TCP/IP isn't enabled. `localhost` by itself worked because a different protocol was used, most likely Shared Memory. Only Shared Memory is enabled by default, which allows connections *only* from the local machine ie localhost.

Comment: That´s right, people. Changing the localhost to an IP address prevents it from working too. The TCP/IP protocol is required for non-shared memory access. Wonder why it comes deactivated, maybe it´s default for the Developer version of SQL Server. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: In my experience the dev version defaults to TCP/IP disabled.  Standard version does too, IIRC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **do** actually specify the port like OP does, the 2 comments are wrong.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

The reason you had to turn on TCP/IP is that you **must** enable TCP/IP for the server to listen on a port, default or otherwise.

The server, **if TCP/IP is on**, defaults to port 1433.  If TCP/IP is not on, then by definition it cannot listen to **any** ports.

Comment: Thanks, found out in the comments that the connection string without the port connects to the database via shared memory access, and you´re right, to listen to an specific port or even connect from another host, the TCP/IP protocol (that is used when the port is specified) has to be activated.